# How to convert a {date} to {time} in pure Vimscript

Tags: vim

How to convert a `date` to `time` in pure Vimscript.

I have a date (ex: 2013-12-21) and I want to convert it to `time` in order to call `strftime()` to get the day of week. Because the 2nd argument of `strftime` must be a `time`, as mentioned `:h strftime()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only sources for `{time}` (which is the Unix epoch, i.e. seconds since 1-Jan-1970) built-in are `localtime()` for the current time, and `getftime()` for a file's modification date.

To convert arbitrary dates, one needs external help; e.g. through an embedded language like Python, or via the `date` command-line tool. You'll find the latter implemented in `ingo#date#epoch#ConvertTo()` from my [ingo-library plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4433).

Comment: OK, I can delete my would-be comment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since version [8.1.2325](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2326) (`:echom has('patch-8.1.2325')`), Vim supports [`strptime()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#strptime%28%29). Thus, that would be something as easy as this:

```
:echom strptime('%Y-%m-%d', '2013-12-21')
```